# JavaFX WebEngine is not tracked in blog statistics of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, javafx

I have notice that a visit from a JavaFx WebEngine is not tracked in the statistics of the website/blog.

Thats the code i use. The website is loaded but if I check my statistics in the wordpress-administration-tool, there is not any visit tracked.

```
public class Example extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    borderPane.setCenter(browser);
    webEngine.load("https://somewordpressblog.wordpress.com/");
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 400, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What are the requirements for the wordpress logging (if any)?  Does it require a valid userAgent or some other header field be populated in order to log the entry?

Comment: I dont know. Where can I get these information? :(